# Detecting that the stack is full

Tags: c++, stack, segmentation-fault, stack-overflow

When writing C++ code I've learned that using the stack to store memory is a good idea.

But recently I ran into a problem:

I had an experiment that had code that looked like this:

```
void fun(const unsigned int N) {
    float data_1[N*N];
    float data_2[N*N];

    /* Do magic */
}
```

The code exploted with a seqmentation fault at random, and I had no idea why.

It turned out that problem was that I was trying to store things that were to big on my stack, is there a way of detecting this? Or at least detecting that it has gone wrong?

Comment: Is your question about C or C++?

Comment: I think you can not initialize an array on the stack using variables in C/C++ !

Comment: How big is your data? I suggest that you store 100KB+ data in heap using malloc/free. (Other people may suggest an even lower bound)

Comment: @MartinKristiansen then why also mark it C?

Comment: Oh come on, how can you resist using the [tag:stackoverflow] tag?

Comment: May be you overrun array boundaries?

Comment: The code you wrote is not valid C++, so I assume you are talking about C99 or C11, those have VLAs.

Comment: g++ allows VLAs in C++ as well, as an extension.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
float data_1[N*N];
float data_2[N*N];
```

These are variable length arrays (VLA), as `N` is not a constant expression. The *const-ness* in the parameter only ensures that `N` is read-only. It doesn't tell the compiler that `N` is constant expression.

VLAs are allowed in C99 only; in other version of C, and all versions of C++ they're not allowed. However, some compilers provides VLA as compiler-extension feature. If you're compiling with GCC, then try using `-pedantic` option, it will tell you it is not allowed.

Now why your program gives segfault, probably because of [stack-overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow) due to large value of `N * N`:

---

Consider using `std::vector` as:

```
#include <vector> 

void fun(const unsigned int N) 
{
  std::vector<float> data_1(N*N);
  std::vector<float> data_2(N*N);

  //your code
}
```

Comment: I added the const to the questing :-)

Comment: const function parameter doesn't change anything here, the value is still only known at runtime so you're still relying on a compiler extension. Anyway be it C or C++, the point is- if you need lots of memory, use heap instead (via `std::vector`).

Comment: @MartinKristiansen: I edited my answer, saying *"The const-ness in the parameter only ensures that `N` is read-only. It doesn't tell the compiler that `N` is constant expression."*

Comment: I was actually not aware that I was using a compiler extention. I'm runing the code on two platforms using Intel icc on Linux and gcc on a mac, and neither of the complain.

Comment: It's a bad idea from the start to use a vector, if you just need an array. This will give the overhead in time (and in memory also). So I would use the simple malloc, instead of using a vector.

Comment: @MartinKristiansen: Try using `-pedantic` option if you're using GCC to compile your code.

Comment: @SPIRiT_1984: In fact, it is bad idea to use `malloc` from the start. Use `std::vector` when you need dynamic array. Use `malloc/new` and manage memory yourself, when you've *very strong reason* to do so.

Answer (score 2):

It's extremely difficult to detect that the stack is full, and not at all portable. One of the biggest problems is that stack frames are of variable size (especially when using variable-length arrays, which are really just a more standard way of doing what people were doing before with `alloca()`) so you can't use simple proxies like the number of stack frames.

One of the simplest methods that is *mostly* portable is to put a variable (probably of type `char` so that a pointer to it is a `char*`) at a known depth on the stack and to then measure the distance from that point to a variable (of the same type) in the current stack frame by simple pointer arithmetic. Add in an estimate of how much space you're about to allocate, and you can have a good guess as to wether the stack is about to blow up on you. The problems with this are that you don't know the direction that the stack is growing in (no, they don't all grow in the same direction!) and working out the size of the stack space is itself rather messy (you can try things like system limits, but they're really quite awkward). Plus the hack factor is very high.

The other trick I've seen used *on 32-bit Windows only* was to try to `alloca()` sufficient space and handle the system exception that would occur if there was insufficient room.

```
int have_enough_stack_space(void) {
    int enough_space = 0;

    __try {           /* Yes, that's got a double-underscore. */
        alloca(SOME_VALUE_THAT_MEANS_ENOUGH_SPACE);
        enough_space = 1;
    }  __except (EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER) {}

    return enough_space;
}
```

This code is *very* non-portable (e.g., don't count on it working on 64-bit Windows) and building with older gcc requires some nasty inline assembler instead! Structured exception handling (which this is a use of) is amongst the blackest of black arts on Windows. (And don't `return` from inside the `__try` construct.)

Comment: This was all based on the stack checking code that was in the implementation of Tcl 8.4; the code with SEH use was converted to using the first pointer-based method in 8.5, and dropped entirely in 8.6 (which uses a “stackless” engine implementation instead, and so doesn't need this sort of thing nearly so much).

Comment: BTW, storing the variable-sized arrays on the heap is going to be far more reliable, especially if you can use RAII-techniques to ensure reliable deletion.

Answer (score 1):

Try using instead functions like malloc. It will return null explicitly, if it failed to find a block of memory of the size you requested.

Of course, in that case don't forget to free this memory in the end of function, after you are done.

Also, you can check the settings of your compiler, with what stack memory limit it generates the binaries.

Comment: Malloc does help -- and using malloc was my sollution, but that means that now I have a pointer to keep track of.

Comment: Yes, that's true about the pointer, but since it is resided inside single function, there is no problem about that. Just add delete at the end of the function

Comment: @MartinKristiansen you don't need to keep track of pointers every time you use dynamic memory. There's a paradigm called `RAII` that simplifies that, google for it. And in the meantime, use a local `std::vector` object

Comment: +1 for compiler settings, which are really the only way to manage the stack.

Comment: @MartinKristiansen Keeping track of a pointer isn't that hard. Allocate the memory at the beginning of the function, and free it at the end and at every `return` statement.

Comment: If yoy want to allocate arrays dynamically, using `std::vector` would be my first choice.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Keeping track of allocated memory manually *is* hard in C++, due to the presence of exceptions. Like Kos said, the best solution is to rely on RAII by using a vector.

Answer (score 1):

One of the reasons people say it is better to use stack instead of heap memory can be because of the fact that variables allocated on top of the stack will be popped out automatically when you leave the body of the function. For storing big blocks of information it is usual to use heap memory and other data structures like linked lists or trees. Also memories allocated on the stack is limited and much more less than you can allocate in the heap space. I think it is better to manage the memory allocation and releasing more carefully instead of trying to use stack for storing big data.

You can use framework which manage your memory allocations. As well you can use VDL to check your memory leaks and memories which is not released.

Comment: That is my point, I've written the code to be 'mostly' used on small 'N's, but one in a while a big N will accure.

Answer (score 1):

> is there a way of detecting this?

No, in general.

Stack size is platform depedent. Typically, *Operating System* decides the size of the stack. So you can check your OS (`ulimit -s` on linux) to see how much stack memory it allocates for your program.

If your compiler supports `stackavail()` then you can check it. It's better to go heap-allocated memory in situations where you are unsure whether you'd exceed the stack limit.

Comment: but here is the thing, I was developing on a Linux box with some highend hardware, and Spend alot of time figuring out why my code did'nt run on my MacBookPro. The Linux box had no problem with a 4 MB stack alloc, but the OSX box did not like it.